# Expand a power to a sum as a product of powers in SymPy

Tags: python, sympy

I want to expand `a**(x+y)` into `a**x a**y`  using SymPy.  I have not been able to do this simple task.

Comment: I made some minor edits your question. Note that inline code is done using a single tick mark. Also, this post does not require [tag:python-3.x], but for posts that do, you should use both that tag and [tag:python], as per the [tag:python-3.x] tag description.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `force=True`:

```
In [1]: x, y, z = symbols('x, y, z')

In [2]: expand(x**(y+z))
Out[2]: 
 y + z
x     

In [3]: expand(x**(y+z), force=True)
Out[3]: 
 y  z
x ⋅x
```

The reason that `force=True` is needed is because the expansion is not mathematically correct for all possible values of the symbols x, y and z which by default as assumed to be something like arbitrary complex numbers.

If you assume that `x` is nonzero then expand will work:

```
In [13]: x = symbols('x', nonzero=True)

In [14]: expand(x**(y+z))
Out[14]: 
 y  z
x ⋅x
```

To see why the nonzero assumption is needed suppose that e.g. `x = 0`, `y = 2` and `z = -1`. The expanded form would be `0**2*0**-1` which is undefined whereas the unexpanded form would be `0**(2-1)` which is not.